# how to fix compiler error for sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

having problem with this line of code, compiler error on getInt method.  because the variable KEY_HITS is a String and not an int.  How do I fix this problem?

```
 total = total + c.getInt(KEY_HITS);
```

here is more of the code;

```
    public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_HITS="persons_hits";

 public int getTotal() {

String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HITS };
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
        null, null);
int total = 0;

for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    total = total + c.getInt(KEY_HITS);
}
return total;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what errors says **because the variable KEY_HITS is a String and not an int**
you need to pass integer parameter in [getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29). You can get column's index by [getColumnIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29)

```
total = total + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HITS));
```